# UICollectionView Custom Layout Middle column starting higher

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView scrolling vertically right now. I would like to have it look like this =, where the middle row starts a little higher than the other two to create a cool and interesting effect. 
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Collection view layout can be achieved by creating a [custom layout class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1).

**Theory:**

Basically, collection view works directly with the custom layout object to manage the overall layout process, asking for the required layout information.

During the layout process, the collection view calls specific methods of the layout object. These methods provide a chance to calculate the position of items and to provide the collection view with the primary information it needs.

Following methods are always called in order during the layout process:

1. [prepare()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617752-prepare): Perform the up-front calculations needed to provide layout information
2. [collectionViewContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617796-collectionviewcontentsize): Return the overall size of the entire content area based on your initial calculations
3. [layoutAttributesForElements(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617769-layoutattributesforelements): Return the attributes for cells and views that are in the specified rectangle

---

**Practical:**

1. **Prerequisite**: Assuming we have a Collection view in place and configured with the
   datasource and delegates, let's create a `UICollectionViewLayout`
   subclass. I named it `HiveLayout`. I also assigned it to the
   `collectionView` in the storyboard. We also need some variable that will be useful in the process

   ```
   //    Properties for configuring the layout: the number of columns and the cell padding.
   fileprivate var numberOfColumns = 3
   fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 10

   //    Cache the calculated attributes. When you call prepare(), you’ll calculate the attributes for all items and add them to the cache. You can be efficient and query the cache instead of recalculating them every time.
   fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

   //    Properties to store the content size.
   fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
   fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
       guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
           return 0
       }
       let insets = collectionView.contentInset
       return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
   }
   ```
2. [**prepare()**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617752-prepare): This is where we will actually calculate the attributes of the cells

   ```
   override func prepare() {
       // If cache is empty and the collection view exists – calculate the layout attributes
       guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
           return
       }

       // xOffset: array with the x-coordinate for every column based on the column widths
       // yOffset: array with the y-position for every column, Using odd-even logic to push the even cell upwards and odd cells down.
       let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
       var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
       for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
           xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
       }
       var column = 0

       var yOffset = [CGFloat]()
       for i in 0..<numberOfColumns {
           yOffset.append((i % 2 == 0) ? (columnWidth / 2) : 0)
       }

       for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

           let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

           // Calculate insetFrame that can be set to the attribute
           let cellHeight = columnWidth - (cellPadding * 2)
           let height = cellPadding * 2 + cellHeight
           let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
           let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

           // Create an instance of UICollectionViewLayoutAttribute, sets its frame using insetFrame and appends the attributes to cache.
           let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
           attributes.frame = insetFrame
           cache.append(attributes)

           // Update the contentHeight to account for the frame of the newly calculated item. It then advances the yOffset for the current column based on the frame
           contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
           yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

           column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
       }
   }
   ```
3. **[collectionViewContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617796-collectionviewcontentsize)**:

   ```
   //    Using contentWidth and contentHeight, calculate collectionViewContentSize.
   override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
   }
   ```
4. **[layoutAttributesForElements(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617769-layoutattributesforelements)**:

   ```
   override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

       var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

       for attributes in cache {
           if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
               visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
           }
       }
       return visibleLayoutAttributes
   }
   ```
5. **[layoutAttributesForItem(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617797-layoutattributesforitem)**: To return attributes for particular cell

   ```
   override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
       return cache[indexPath.item]
   }
   ```

Please check out the [gist](https://gist.github.com/VivekMolkar/1676e067c66db96ece5cf7fb1399caed) for the Layout Class.

Here it is in action!!

[image: Demo]

Comment: How would I make it that the first cell is the top one rather than the right one

Comment: Will be happy to help, can you elaborate?

Comment: The first cell now is the one that appears on the right column, i would like to make it that the center column fills first if possible do you know how I could do that

Comment: I believe this is achievable, can you try tweaking the above code? check if `xOffset` and `yOffset` values help. some maths should required..